# Generate Method Definition for button from XML onClick in Eclipse?

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I have generated Button in Android xml, using tutorial, simply as below

```
<Button
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:text="@string/self_destruct"
     android:onClick="selfDestruct" />
```

Here Method **selfDestruct** is being called on button press. Is there any way to create body of methods, where this XML is used like below

```
 public void selfDestruct(View view) {
     // Comments about Method....
 }
```

Comment: I think you need to create it manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it can be difficult to generate this method **in the right place** because it can be in a **lot of places** (Activities) or just in an `abstract Activity`.

In case of `Fragment`, it can be more difficult to generate it in the right place by `eclipse/ADT`.

I think that's why this method is not generated by `eclipse/ADT`.

Well, you have to write it manually in my own opinion.